# Get custom price on cart Magento

Tags: php, magento, events, observers

i have created a new attribute products (price2) with different price respect standard price of magento.

I have modified view.phtml and catalog view to show price2 if standard price is higher, but i have a problem if add to cart product with price2; the product's price not respect price2 but standard price of magento.

How can resolve this problem? I have think use observer, but i can't communicate price2.

Comment: Why don't you use special_price? It does exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't use special price.

Comment: Can you explain why? Because the process of making another price attribute is more complicated than you may have tought. Catalog price rules, sales rules, tier prices, customer group prices they are all considered in calculations. So it's not just adding to catalog template and using an observer. In my opinion, if you really can't use special price, you may need to consider other options like catalog price rules.

Comment: as @muhammedv suggested, Special price will the best option. Please provide why can't you use that along with the problem using observer.